# How to identify the color of a shape using EmguCV

Tags: c#, emgucv

I am developing an application which can identify basic shapes and their colors. Identifying shape part is done Now I want to identify the color of that shapes.I am using EmguCV libraries. Is there any one help me?

Comment: Can you add some details about what you have tried? Thanks

Comment: I do not have any idea how to get the color of that particular shape

Answer (score 2):

[Shape Detection and Color Filtering in Emgu CV](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IPsaqKmErgs)

This is the edited code in C# (According to the previously mentioned video in visual basic)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.CvEnum;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.CV.UI;

namespace EmguCVShapeDetector
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //---Variables--//

    bool blnFirstTimeInResizeEvent = true;
    int OriginalFormWidth;
    int OriginalFormHeight;
    int OriginalTableLayoutPanelWidth;
    int OriginalTableLayoutPanelHeight;



    Capture capwebcam;
    bool webCamCapturingInProcess = false;

    Image<Bgr, Byte> imgOriginal;
    Image<Bgr, Byte> imgSmoothed;
    Image<Gray, Byte> imgGrayColorFiltered;
    Image<Gray, Byte> imgCanny;
    Image<Bgr, Byte> imgCircles;
    Image<Bgr, Byte> imgLines;
    Image<Bgr, Byte> imgTrisRectsPolys;

    Double dbMinBlue = 0.0;
    double dbMinGreen = 0.0;
    double dbMinRed = 0.0;
    double dbMaxBlue = 0.0;
    double dbMaxGreen = 0.0;
    double dbMaxRed = 0.0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        OriginalFormWidth = this.Width;
        OriginalFormHeight = this.Height;
        OriginalTableLayoutPanelWidth = tlpLebelsAndImageBoxes.Width;
        OriginalTableLayoutPanelHeight = tlpLebelsAndImageBoxes.Height;

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 255; i++)
        {
            cmbMinBlue.Items.Add(i);
            cmbMinGreen.Items.Add(i);
            cmbMinRed.Items.Add(i);
            cmbMaxBlue.Items.Add(i+1);
            cmbMaxGreen.Items.Add(i+1);
            cmbMaxRed.Items.Add(i+1);

        }

        cmbMinBlue.Text = "0";
        cmbMinGreen.Text = "0";
        cmbMinRed.Text = "0";
        cmbMaxBlue.Text = "1";
        cmbMaxGreen.Text = "1";
        cmbMaxRed.Text = "1";
    }

    private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(blnFirstTimeInResizeEvent == true)
        {
            blnFirstTimeInResizeEvent = false;
        }
        else
        {
            tlpLebelsAndImageBoxes.Width = this.Width - (OriginalTableLayoutPanelWidth);
            tlpLebelsAndImageBoxes.Height = this.Height - (OriginalTableLayoutPanelHeight);
        }
    }

    private void radImageFile_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(radImageFile.Checked == true)
        {
            if(webCamCapturingInProcess == true)
            {
                Application.Idle -= ProcessImageAndUpdateGUI;
                webCamCapturingInProcess = false;
            }

            ibOriginal.Image = null;
            ibGrayColorFilter.Image = null;
            ibCanny.Image = null;
            ibCircles.Image = null;
            ibLines.Image = null;
            ibTrianglesAndPolys.Image = null;

            lblFile.Visible = true;
            txtFile.Visible = true;
            btnFile.Visible = true;

        }
    }
    private void radWebCam_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(radWebCam.Checked == true)
        {
            try
            {
                capwebcam = new Capture();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
            Application.Idle += ProcessImageAndUpdateGUI;
            webCamCapturingInProcess = true;

            lblFile.Visible = false;
            txtFile.Visible = false;
            btnFile.Visible = false;

        }
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(capwebcam != null)
        {
            capwebcam.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private void btnFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ofdFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Image inputImage = Image.FromFile(ofdFile.FileName);
            txtFile.Text = ofdFile.FileName.ToString();

        }
    }

    private void chbDrawCirclesOnOriginalImage_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(webCamCapturingInProcess == false)
        {
            ProcessImageAndUpdateGUI(new object(), new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    private void chbDrawLinesOnOriginalImage_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (webCamCapturingInProcess == false)
        {
            ProcessImageAndUpdateGUI(new object(), new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    private void chbDrawTrianglesAndPolygansOnOriginalImage_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (webCamCapturingInProcess == false)
        {
            ProcessImageAndUpdateGUI(new object(), new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    private void chbFillterOnColor_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(chbFillterOnColor.Checked == true)
        {
            lblBlue.Visible = true;
            lblGreen.Visible = true;
            lblRed.Visible = true;
            lblMin.Visible = true;
            lblMax.Visible = true;
            cmbMinBlue.Visible = true;
            cmbMinGreen.Visible = true;
            cmbMinRed.Visible = true;
            cmbMaxBlue.Visible = true;
            cmbMaxGreen.Visible = true;
            cmbMaxRed.Visible = true;
            lblGrayColorFilter.Text = "gray (color filtered):";
            ProcessImageAndUpdateGUI(new object(), new EventArgs());


        }
        else if (chbFillterOnColor.Checked == false)
        {
            lblBlue.Visible = false;
            lblGreen.Visible = false;
            lblRed.Visible = false;
            lblMin.Visible = false;
            lblMax.Visible = false;
            cmbMinBlue.Visible = false;
            cmbMinGreen.Visible = false;
            cmbMinRed.Visible = false;
            cmbMaxBlue.Visible = false;
            cmbMaxGreen.Visible = false;
            cmbMaxRed.Visible = false;
            lblGrayColorFilter.Text = "gray:";
            ProcessImageAndUpdateGUI(new object(), new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    private void txtFile_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtFile.SelectionStart = txtFile.Text.Length;
    }

    private void cmbMinBlue_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(chbFillterOnColor.Checked == true && txtFile.Text != "")
        {

            dbMinBlue = Convert.ToDouble(cmbMinBlue.Text);
            ProcessImageAndUpdateGUI(new object(), new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    private void cmbMinGreen_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (chbFillterOnColor.Checked == true && txtFile.Text != "")
        {
            dbMinGreen = Convert.ToDouble(cmbMinGreen.Text);
            ProcessImageAndUpdateGUI(new object(), new EventArgs());
        }


    }

    private void cmbMinRed_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (chbFillterOnColor.Checked == true && txtFile.Text != "")
        {
            dbMinRed = Convert.ToDouble(cmbMinRed.Text);
            ProcessImageAndUpdateGUI(new object(), new EventArgs());
        }

    }

    private void cmbMaxBlue_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (chbFillterOnColor.Checked == true && txtFile.Text != "")
        {
            dbMaxBlue = Convert.ToDouble(cmbMaxBlue.Text);
            ProcessImageAndUpdateGUI(new object(), new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    private void cmbMaxGreen_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (chbFillterOnColor.Checked == true && txtFile.Text != "")
        {
            dbMaxGreen = Convert.ToDouble(cmbMaxGreen.Text);
            ProcessImageAndUpdateGUI(new object(), new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    private void cmbMaxRed_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (chbFillterOnColor.Checked == true && txtFile.Text != "")
        {
            dbMaxRed = Convert.ToDouble(cmbMaxRed.Text);
            ProcessImageAndUpdateGUI(new object(), new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    private void cmbMinBlue_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(cmbMinBlue.Text) < 0 || Convert.ToInt32(cmbMinBlue.Text) > 255)
        {
            cmbMinBlue.Text = "0";
        }
        cmbMinBlue_SelectedIndexChanged(new object(), new EventArgs());
    }

    private void cmbMinGreen_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(cmbMinGreen.Text) < 0 || Convert.ToInt32(cmbMinGreen.Text) > 255)
        {
            cmbMinGreen.Text = "0";
        }
        cmbMinGreen_SelectedIndexChanged(new object(), new EventArgs());
    }

    private void cmbMinRed_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(cmbMinRed.Text) < 0 || Convert.ToInt32(cmbMinRed.Text) > 255)
        {
            cmbMinRed.Text = "0";
        }
        cmbMinRed_SelectedIndexChanged(new object(), new EventArgs());
    }

    private void cmbMaxBlue_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(cmbMaxBlue.Text) < 1 || Convert.ToInt32(cmbMaxBlue.Text) > 256)
        {
            cmbMaxBlue.Text = "1";
        }
        cmbMaxBlue_SelectedIndexChanged(new object(), new EventArgs());
    }

    private void cmbMaxGreen_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(cmbMaxGreen.Text) < 1 || Convert.ToInt32(cmbMaxGreen.Text) > 256)
        {
            cmbMaxGreen.Text = "1";
        }
        cmbMaxGreen_SelectedIndexChanged(new object(), new EventArgs());
    }

    private void cmbMaxRed_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(cmbMaxRed.Text) < 1 || Convert.ToInt32(cmbMaxRed.Text) > 256)
        {
            cmbMaxRed.Text = "1";
        }
        cmbMaxRed_SelectedIndexChanged(new object(), new EventArgs());
    }

    private void cmbMinBlue_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.Enter) || e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.Return))
        {
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            lblOriginal.Focus(); 
        }
    }

    private void cmbMinGreen_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.Enter) || e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.Return))
        {
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            lblOriginal.Focus();
        }
    }

    private void cmbMinRed_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.Enter) || e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.Return))
        {
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            lblOriginal.Focus();
        }
    }

    private void cmbMaxBlue_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.Enter) || e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.Return))
        {
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            lblOriginal.Focus();
        }
    }

    private void cmbMaxGreen_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.Enter) || e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.Return))
        {
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            lblOriginal.Focus();
        }
    }

    private void cmbMaxRed_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.Enter) || e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.Return))
        {
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            lblOriginal.Focus();
        }
    }

    void ProcessImageAndUpdateGUI(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(radImageFile.Checked == true)
        {
            try
            {
                imgOriginal = new Image<Bgr,Byte>(txtFile.Text);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        else if(radWebCam.Checked == true)
        {
            try
            {
                imgOriginal = capwebcam.QueryFrame();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        if(imgOriginal == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        imgSmoothed = imgOriginal.PyrDown().PyrUp();
        imgSmoothed._SmoothGaussian(3);

        if(chbFillterOnColor.Checked == true)
        {
            imgGrayColorFiltered = imgSmoothed.InRange(new Bgr(dbMinBlue,dbMinGreen,dbMinRed),new Bgr(dbMaxBlue,dbMaxGreen,dbMaxRed));
            imgGrayColorFiltered = imgGrayColorFiltered.PyrDown().PyrUp();
            imgGrayColorFiltered._SmoothGaussian(3);

        }
        else if(chbFillterOnColor.Checked == false)
        {
            imgGrayColorFiltered = imgSmoothed.Convert<Gray, Byte>();
        }

        Gray grayCannyThreshold = new Gray(160);
        Gray grayCircleAccumThreshold = new Gray(100);
        Gray grayThreshLinking = new Gray(80);

        imgCanny = imgGrayColorFiltered.Canny(grayCannyThreshold, grayThreshLinking);

        imgCircles = imgOriginal.CopyBlank();
        imgLines = imgOriginal.CopyBlank();
        imgTrisRectsPolys = imgOriginal.CopyBlank();


        Double dblAccumRes = 2.0;
        Double dblMinDistBetweenCircles = imgGrayColorFiltered.Height / 4;
        int intMinRadius = 10;
        int intMaxRadius = 400;

        CircleF[] circles = imgGrayColorFiltered.HoughCircles(grayCannyThreshold, grayCircleAccumThreshold, dblAccumRes, dblMinDistBetweenCircles, intMinRadius, intMaxRadius)[0];

        foreach(CircleF circle in circles)
        {
            imgCircles.Draw(circle, new Bgr(Color.Red),2);
            if(chbDrawCirclesOnOriginalImage.Checked == true)
            {
                imgCircles.Draw(circle, new Bgr(Color.Red), 2);

            }
        }

        Double dblRhoRes = 1.0;
        Double dblThetaRes = 4.0 *(Math.PI/180.0);
        int intThreshold = 20;
        Double dblMinLineWidth = 30.0;
        Double dblMinGapBetweenLines = 10.0;

        LineSegment2D[] lines = imgCanny.Clone().HoughLinesBinary(dblRhoRes, dblThetaRes, intThreshold, dblMinLineWidth, dblMinGapBetweenLines)[0];

        foreach(LineSegment2D line in lines)
        {
            imgLines.Draw(line, new Bgr(Color.DarkGreen),2);
            if(chbDrawLinesOnOriginalImage.Checked == true)
            {
                imgOriginal.Draw(line, new Bgr(Color.DarkGreen),2);
            }
        }

        Contour<Point> contours = imgCanny.FindContours();
        List<Triangle2DF> lstTreangles = new List<Triangle2DF>();
        List<MCvBox2D> lstRectangles = new List<MCvBox2D>();
        List<Contour<Point>> lstPoluhons = new List<Contour<Point>>();

        while(contours != null)
        {
            Contour<Point> contour = contours.ApproxPoly(10.0);

            if(contour.Area > 250.0)
            {
                if(contour.Total == 3)
                {
                    Point[] ptPoints = contour.ToArray(); 
                    lstTreangles.Add(new Triangle2DF(ptPoints[0],ptPoints[1],ptPoints[2]));
                }
                else if(contour.Total >= 4 && contour.Total <= 6)
                {
                    Point[] ptPoints = contour.ToArray(); 
                    Boolean blnIsRectangle = true;

                    if(contour.Total == 4)
                    {
                        LineSegment2D[] ls2dEdges = PointCollection.PolyLine(ptPoints, true);

                        for(int i = 0; i< ls2dEdges.Length -1; i++)
                        {
                            Double dblAngle = Math.Abs(ls2dEdges[(i+1) % ls2dEdges.Length].GetExteriorAngleDegree(ls2dEdges[i]));
                            if(dblAngle < 80.0 || dblAngle > 100.0)
                            {
                                blnIsRectangle = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        blnIsRectangle = false;
                    }

                    if(blnIsRectangle)
                    {
                        lstRectangles.Add(contour.GetMinAreaRect());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lstPoluhons.Add(contour);
                    }
                }
            }



            contours = contours.HNext;
        }


        foreach(Triangle2DF triangle in lstTreangles)
        {
           imgTrisRectsPolys.Draw(triangle, new Bgr(Color.Yellow),2);
            if(chbDrawTrianglesAndPolygansOnOriginalImage.Checked == true)
            {
                imgOriginal.Draw(triangle, new Bgr(Color.Yellow),2);
            }
        }

        foreach(MCvBox2D rect in lstRectangles)
        {
            imgTrisRectsPolys.Draw(rect, new Bgr(Color.Blue),2);
            if(chbDrawTrianglesAndPolygansOnOriginalImage.Checked == true)
            {
                imgOriginal.Draw(rect, new Bgr(Color.Blue),2);
            }
        }

        foreach(Contour<Point> contPoly in lstPoluhons)
        {
            imgTrisRectsPolys.Draw(contPoly, new Bgr(Color.Gray),2);
            if(chbDrawTrianglesAndPolygansOnOriginalImage.Checked == true)
            {
                imgOriginal.Draw(contPoly, new Bgr(Color.Gray),2);
            }
        }

        ibOriginal.Image = imgOriginal;
        ibGrayColorFilter.Image = imgGrayColorFiltered;
        ibCanny.Image = imgCanny;
        ibLines.Image = imgLines;
        ibTrianglesAndPolys.Image = imgTrisRectsPolys;


    }


  }
}
```

I think this code will helpful to your project.

Comment: The link seems to be very helpful indeed, but please add at least a gist of what needs to be done to determine the color of a shape.

Comment: Thank You Very much I watched that video but it was written in VB I want to know how to do this using C#

Comment: @Bhagya Give me few days. I will convert that code in to C# and let you know.